# Add items to a User via front end tags, (ie. travel Itineraries)

Tags: safecracker, users

I'm working on a travel site and one of the requests is to create user itineraries. I was planning on using Zoo Visitor for some of the user functionality, but wondering if there is any add-ons that I could use to allow a user to just click a button on an event/attraction and have it added to an itinerary tied to their account.

One potential option might be to have a Safe Cracker on each page and have all the field be hidden. Then when they click the button, have that submit a form which would create an itinerary item which would relate to the user. Are there any better/simpler solutions? Checked devotee and couldn't find anything that seemed to match, but I could be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want a favorite/bookmark addon. Check out [Remember Me](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/remember-me) or [others](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=favorites&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2) depending on your specific needs. ie. saved to session, save to member account, etc.

Comment: brilliant! Thanks, hadn't thought about that a favorites option, although it makes perfect sense. I really like the look of Remember Me.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Comment: Remember Me is an excellent add-on. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with Solspace Favorites. I've used a different method with safecracker but it's a bit more complicated and time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at this today, it might just be the thing you need! - http://squarebit.co.uk/shortlist

Comment: Do you know if this or any, would allow sorting/rearranging favorites? I couldn't find anything. I guess I could always change the dates that the item was favorited to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Shortlist was built for a tourism site specifically for a users itinerary, it does not require a member to be logged in to use it. The dev (Joel) is very supportive and there's a nice little demo here: http://shortlist.squarebit.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

My personal recommendation is [Solspace Favourites](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/favorites/) for this. We've used it for "wish lists" which could work as travel itineraries (if you're not too concerned about the time component).

Comment: I wouldn't mind being able to add time abilities, but that looks like it may make it a lot more complicated. Are there any "easy" ways to add time ability to this?